Proof of existence of $\epsilon$-nets in infinite metric spaces.
The following is an excerpt from these lecture notes:

Given a metric space $(X, d)$, a subset $Y$ of $X$ is said to be an
$\epsilon$-net if

For $a, b \in Y$, we have $d(a, b) \geq \epsilon$.
For all $x \in X$, there exists an $a \in Y$ such that $d(x, a)<\epsilon$.

For every finite metric space $X$ and every $\epsilon>0$, it is clear
that there exists an $\epsilon$-net. It can easily be found by the
following greedy algorithm: Start with a single point in the net $N$.
While there exists a point $x \in X$ such that $\min _{a \in N} d(a,x)>\epsilon$, add $x$ to $N$, and repeat. Clearly since $X$ is finite
this terminates, and we are left with an $\epsilon$-net at the end.
Using Zorn's lemma one can argue this even for infinite metric spaces,
but we will not go into the proof.

Question
My question is about the last point from the excerpt. Can anyone point me to a reference for a proof on the existence of $\epsilon$-nets in arbitrary metric spaces? Or at least the idea of how Zorn's lemma is applied?

Let $\mathcal{Y} = \{Y_\alpha\}_\alpha$ denote the poset of subsets $Y_\alpha \subseteq X$ with the property that $d(a, b) \geq \epsilon$ for all $a, b \in Y_\alpha$, partially ordered by inclusion. If $Y$ is a maximal element of $\mathcal{Y}$, then that means there are no points $x \in X$ such that $d(a, x) \geq \epsilon$ for all $a \in Y$, since otherwise $Y \cup \{x\} > Y$ in the partial ordering. But this just means that $Y$ satisfies condition (2) as well as (1), so $Y$ is an $\epsilon$-set. Therefore we need only prove that $\mathcal{Y}$ has a maximal element.
So suppose we have a chain $\{Y_i\}_i$ in $\mathcal{Y}$. Then this chain has an upper bound in $\mathcal{Y}$ given by $\bigcup_i Y_i$–I'll leave you to check this. Hence by Zorn's lemma $\mathcal{Y}$ has a maximal element.

If you haven't seen this type of argument before, look at some more classic applications of Zorn! I like "every ring has a maximal ideal", "the nilradical is the intersection of all primes", and "every vector space has a basis."
